# Advice anti-theft remember me cookie

Tags: php, cookies

I have tried to implement the logic with a token and a persistent token. The token get's regenerated for the cookie when the cookie is recognized.

What I don't get is how to implement it in the database. One example ( if you google github rememberme) is inserting a new entry in the db with a new token when a cookie is recognized.

But in that particular example, every second time you want the cookie to be validated it will cause a mismatch due to that query wich does a pdo fetchColumn with the where clauses fixed on the persistent token and the userid AND LIMIT 1. This will always result in the first matched row and not the last entry wich contains the regenerated token.

I hope it is understandable because I am not typing code because I typed it on my iphone. What is the correct way if your base implementation revolves around those two rokend.

Thanks

Comment: Use order by (token date) DESC?

Comment: Would this protect against cookie theft? I get the feeling I  am overthinking this to much, sorry About that.

Comment: I personally don't like cookies at all. Everything that's stored client side is corrupted OR evil by default, in my book.

Answer (score 0):

What are you writing is not a protection for cookies.

Try to read topics about browser fingerprinting and bind the cookies to the remote IP's.
If something changes like ip or browser id, your cookie might be stolen.

Comment: Thankyou, I will google it, I already new about the useragent and the ip, but I was really curious about the token implementation and when to invalidate a login